# Firebase Firestore Web SDK cannot seem to connect when user is logged in

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an odd problem, which I'm hoping is either a misunderstanding on my part or a misconfiguration somewhere.

I am trying to use the Firebase Firestore web sdk to retrieve data. When I make read calls to Firestore in my webapp as an un-authenticated user, the reads return fine, as expected.

However, when I'm logged in as a user (either email/password auth or Facebook auth), I get an error:

`Could not reach Firestore backend.`

When I set the logging level to `debug`, I see this:

`Firestore (4.8.1) 2017-12-24T01:08:15.146Z [PersistentStream]: close with error: FirebaseError: [code=unknown]: Fetching auth token failed: Cannot redefine property: refreshToken`

Which seems highly related.

Has anyone else encountered this or have a sense of what may be going on?

Thanks!

Comment: I've not seen this error before and I wasn't able to reproduce it using the 4.8.1 SDK. Can you provide a jsfiddle or similar to demonstrate the error? That would help immensely in tracking it down.

Comment: Hi @MichaelLehenbauer - can I grant you access to a private github repo to take a look? I have two copies of the code with this issue, one a next.js app, the other a create-react-app.

Comment: Sorry, but not really. In order to investigate we need a minimal repro, ideally that doesn't involve react or next.js.